# How to create Multiple Datasource in JasperReports Server?

Tags: database, jasperserver

I use *JasperReports Server 5.5 community edition*. My company has 3 branches. Each Branch has each database (datasource), but it use the same report.

How to use the same report in 3 branches? Please advise me to solve this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are designing your report using iReport/ Jaspersoft Studio, there in you could create sub-datasets in your report and then use it in your report, either by using lists or by using subreports or tables or whatever suits your purpose.

Then in the Jasper Server you need to add all the three different datasources, and then upload your report giving references to these datasources, in case of sub reports you need to add the JRXML's as the resources to the main report while uploading and JasperServer would consider various datasources.

Hope that this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But you don't understand my question. Ex. Report-A has datasource-A in Branch-1, and it has datasource-B in Branch-B, and it has datasource-C in Branch-C. Report-A has same structure, but it has 3 datasources, because 3 branches have their own database. I can create report that has difference datasource.(this link http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/multiple-datasources-ireport-lists-tables-and-subreports) But I can't create multiple-datasource  in jasperserver. pls help me again